# Why does the while loop in the below code not work?

Tags: python

```
a = 0
suma = 0

while( a <= 1000):
    if (a%3 == 0 or a%5 == 0):
        suma = suma + a
        a = a + 1

print("The final answer is: %s " % suma)
```

Question:
 Find the sum of all multiples of 3 or 5 up till 1000.

I do know how to solve this problem by using a for loop, what I want to know is that why, when  I run this code, it never shows output like a never-ending code statement. I just want to know how to do this through while loop. Thanks for your feedback :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should increment the value of `a` regardless of if it's a multiple of 3 or 5

```
while( a <= 1000):
    if (a%3 == 0 or a%5 == 0):
        suma = suma + a
    a = a + 1
```

Currently, it is never getting past `a = 1` because 1 is neither a multiple of 3 nor 5 so it never increments

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I'm sorry that it's a silly mistake, i just started python. :D

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's because your loop does never increment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the increment line out of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is not very Python styled. Try instead:

```
sum_a = 0

for a in xrange(1001):
    if a%3 == 0 or a%5 == 0:
        sum_a += a

print("The final answer is: {}".format(str(sum_a)))
```

`xrange(1001)` will generate the values at each iteration for `a`. This is much more efficient and quicker than mutating a every interaction.

This way will tend to be clearer and spare a lot of mistakes.